# Not able to store files to mongodb Atlas using gridfs

Tags: gridfs, mongodb-atlas

I am just trying to store some files on to mongodb Atlas database using Gridfs
But, when I click the upload button it shows database connection not open.

```
mongoose.connect(mongodbURL,{useNewUrlParser:true}).then((conn)=>{
    console.log("Database Connection Successful");
}).catch(err=>{
    console.log(err);
});

let gfs;

connection.once('open',()=>{
    gfs = Grid(connection.db,mongoose.mongo);
    gfs.collection('uploads');
})

var storage = new GridFsStorage({
    url: mongodbURL,
    file: (req, file) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
          if (err) {
            return reject(err);
          }
          const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname);
          const fileInfo = {
            filename: filename,
            root:'uploads'
          };
          resolve(fileInfo);
        });
      });
    }
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

router.post('/dashboard/uploads', upload.single('file') ,(req,res)=>{
    res.json({file:req.file});
})
```

> Error: The database connection must be open to store files
>       at GridFSStorage._handleFile (D:\Web Development\e-portal\node_modules\multer-gridfs-storage\lib\gridfs.js:341:17)
>       at D:\Web Development\e-portal\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:144:17
>       at allowAll (D:\Web Development\e-portal\node_modules\multer\index.js:8:3)
>       at wrappedFileFilter (D:\Web Development\e-portal\node_modules\multer\index.js:44:7)
>       at Busboy. (D:\Web Development\e-portal\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:114:7)
>       at Busboy.emit (events.js:198:13)
>       at Busboy.emit (D:\Web Development\e-portal\node_modules\busboy\lib\main.js:38:33)
>       at PartStream. (D:\Web Development\e-portal\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:213:13)
>       at PartStream.emit (events.js:198:13)
>       at HeaderParser. (D:\Web Development\e-portal\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:51:16)
>       at HeaderParser.emit (events.js:198:13)
>       at HeaderParser._finish (D:\Web Development\e-portal\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:68:8)
>       at SBMH. (D:\Web Development\e-portal\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:40:12)
>       at SBMH.emit (events.js:198:13)
>       at SBMH._sbmh_feed (D:\Web Development\e-portal\node_modules\streamsearch\lib\sbmh.js:159:14)
>       at SBMH.push (D:\Web Development\e-portal\node_modules\streamsearch\lib\sbmh.js:56:14)